# $\sin(2\pi i) = ?$ (imaginary '$i$' inside the paranthesis)

Tags: complex-analysis

$\sin(2\pi i)$ equals what ?

I tried Euler's formula and got $-267.74i$ , i.e. $$\frac{e^{2\pi i} - e^{-2\pi i}}{2i}$$

but I don't think it would be right, because $|\sin x| \leq 1$ always, right ?

So, how to find this value. (question by IISc in a competitive exam)

Answer (score 2):

$|\sin(x) \le 1|$ is true on the real line. On the imaginary axis $\sin$ behaves llike $\sinh$ on the real line.

Comment: Thank you Thomas (really quick reply). So, would 267.75 be right ? (sin(2*pi*i) = 267.75) ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin(ix)=i\sinh(x)$$
so
$$\sin(2\pi i)=i\sinh(2\pi)$$
which is approximately $267\cdot7i$.

The inequality $|\sin x|\le1$ is **not** valid when $x$ is non-real.

Comment: thank you brother, :) Helped.

Answer (score -1):

We need to use $$2i\sin x=e^{ix}-e^{-ix}$$

Now $\sin^2z+\cos^2z=1$ holds true for all complex/real $z$

$$\cos^2z=1-\sin^2z$$

Now only for real $\cos z,\cos^2z\ge0$  consequently, we need $$1-\sin^2z\ge0\iff-1\le\sin z\le1$$

Comment: Wish I  know the mistake here

Comment: I didn't downvote, but 1. You seem to ignore the fact the OP knows how to get sine from Euler's Formula. 2. The phrase "we need" gives the impression that the OP's misconception is correct, especially since you end on an inequality implying sine is real. It's true that you say in the middle "only for real cos $z $", but this could be lost in the wording of your answer. 3. This is more minor, but you dont support your claims about real cosine, or the pythagorean identity, or the implicit claim that cosine can be nonreal.